# i/o failure: java.net.UnKnownHostException

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Working on an Android application...

I'm getting this error message:

```
i/o failure: java.net.UnKnownHostException: Unable to resolve host
"api.parse.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Many suggest to add internet permission in the manifest file, I have these permissions already:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure your device has an internet connection ?

Comment: @Felix Karlsson are you testing on device or Avd.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that the device is
>   not connected to the private LAN that has
>   the DNS server that resolves the hostname. The emulator shares the network
>   connectivity of its host; not so the
>   real device.
>   The error says that the dns server the device is talking to can't resolve
>   the name.  It may also mean we can't talk to the dns server.

You have these two entries in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I don't think there might be other reason for that except the connection.